# Can i make a pc password lock system with batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I made an alphanumeric password checker using one-by-one char inputs via `choice` command.
I was to register it to start programs and lock my pc.
But it cannot catch **CTRL-C** terminating.
Piping `echo N` solution did not help me
because it recieves keyboard inputs.
How do i prevent users from typing CTRL-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this site: [Dos Tips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3245&sid=89270710b3cd3a81d867acc6cd7ec509&start=15)

```
 The solution that I found to block CTRL+C aka Terminate Batch Y/N COMPLETELY.

No Fuss, No kidding, No Breaking Out. XOUT but that too can be disabled.

Briefly:

Code:
C:\PROFILES\ADMIN>REN "%COMSPEC:~0,-8%\CSRSS.EXE" !!!CSRSS.!!!



OOPS Windows File Protection. If WFP is enabled ask almighty Google about that.

Transpose the file names to undo. WARNING: This MAY also break your toaster. 8)

PRO: Disallow all programs from injecting code via CSRSS hooking.

CON: PROPERTIES from the System Menu of CMD Windows are disabled as well.

CON: Enemy Territory will certainly whine until dialog box is dismissed once.

ELSE This is bulletproof. I'm being extremely terse!
```

I would recommend reading the other page and some of the info on it before you run the script as it could be damaging.  If you have a VM to test it on that would be best :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it!